# Is it possible to use :before selector for something like this?

Tags: css

I need to make something like this.
It´s not seen very much, bot the box with arrow is not a part of the button.It´s in the front of it. Is it possible to do this using :before selector? Buttons are classical navigation list. Thanks for your help[image]

Comment: sorry. I already edited question.

Answer (score 1):

It most certainly is possible. You may also use an image instead of the appending the ">"

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li { background: gold;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white;
}

li:before {
    content: ">";
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hmm. I did something similar to this and the result wasn't  same. Thanks for your answer. I gave me idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Make the :before element be an absolutely positioned block within the relatively positioned main button.

Then, simply give it the appropriate height, background color and border. You can use FontAwesome and the `content` property to set it to display an arrow.

Comment: I don't think you need to control their positions.

Comment: Touché, it was just one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
body{padding: 20px;}

div{
    margin-left: 64px;
    position: relative;
    background: orange;
    height: 64px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 64px;
    text-indent: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder
}

div:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: -134px;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 64px;
    height:  64px;
    width: 64px;
    background: orange
}
div:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -90px;
    top: 16px;
    margin-left: 32px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: 8px solid white;
    border-right: 8px solid white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>Some Text </div>
```